# Jenkins - changing pom.xml versions manually

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pom.xml

I need to change a project version and I can do it by creating a Maven project and add Maven goal of versions:set. I can also do manually.

**Question**: Is there any downside of changing `pom.xml` versions manually (using sed/awk)?

Comment: Its absolutely right to set the version by editing the pom.xml, but be sure not to forget to change it everywhere (in submodules, dependencies,..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the version using a Maven plugin is definitely better than a manual approach (e.g. `sed`/`awk`) for several reasons:

- You stay within the Maven ecosystem and as such avoid undesirable and unforeseen side effects
- The `versions:set` would also automatically take care of propagating the change to sub-modules, in case of multi-module Maven project, since the [goal](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html):

  > Sets the current project's version and based on that change propagates that change onto any child modules as necessary.
- You can make use of several additional options provided by the goal, like filtering (e.g. only change for certain groupId/artifactId, again in case of multi-module)
- Maintenance wise, you have better chances to keep it solid across different versions of Maven
- In general, if Maven (or one of its plugins) already provides the same functionality: simply don't reinvent the wheel